# No salen mis peticiones HTTP en android Ionic 4

Tags: android, ionic, http, angular7, ionic4

Tengo algunos problemas con las peticiones http de mi aplicación echa con **Ionic 5.2.4** y **Angular 8.2.0**.

Cuando esta aplicación la utilizo en el escritorio en modo de desarrollo todo funciona bien. Sin embargo cuando la compilo para debuguearla en un dispositivo android esta ya no funciona.

Leí que era porque no tenia permisos la app. Asi que agregue esta lina de codigo en el **congif.xml**

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
```

Pero aun así no funciona. No se como puedo modificar el archivo **platforms/android/app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml**
Para poder declarar el url del servicio api.

Este es el error que me sale.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi servidor esta habilitado para no generar los **Cross origin requests**

Tienen alguna recomendación o si quieren que comparta algo de código solo díganme que parte. (No lo comparto directamente porque vuelve muy larga la pregunta)

Comment: Que target SDK estas usando para tu proyecto? Que error te muestra?. Solo tienes esto "<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />" en tu  congif.xml, te sugiero añadirlo

Comment: Hola Alberto. Podrías probar con postman la misma url, puede que muestre algo mas de información y saber si, algo mas, si te da una respuesta ya sea cual sea, si puedes mostrar la.